# how does yarn workspace resolve cli package with many versions

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

assume I have a yarn workspace that have a few packages included the same CLI package, but different versions.

e.g

```
packageA => cliTool@1.0.0
packageB => cliTool@2.0.0
packageC => cliTool@3.0.0
```

Then after install, for `<project root>/node_module/.bin/cliTool` , which version of the cli is it linked to?

Comment: You can probably easily check by just running `yarn cliTool --version`

Comment: @rschristian yes, it works. But what I want to ask is what is the logic for yarn workspace to pick which one it links to. lowest version? highest version? or simply depends on install order?